# string as parameter?

Tags: c++, string, parameters, reference

**If i am not going to modify a string then is the first option better or are both same-** (I just want to iterate through the string, but since string size is big I don't want local copy to be made.)

```
int getString(string& str1) {
    //code
}


int getString (string str1) {
    //code
}
```

**And if I do plan on changing the string, then is there any difference between the two? Is it because strings are immutable in C++?**

Comment: Strings aren't immutable in C++. If you don't need to modify it, just pass by const reference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

String literals are immutable, `std::string`s are not.

The first one is pass-by-reference. If you don't plan on modifying the string, pass it by `const` reference.

The second is pass-by-value - if you do modify the string inside the function, you'd only be modifying a copy, so it's moot.

Comment: so if i pass by reference and change the string, the original string will be changed? not a copy, unlike java?

Comment: @ofey - yes, but last time I used Java I'm pretty sure that class types (i.e. non-fundamental) types are also passed by reference, not value. It may be a difference between `string` and `String` in Java though.

Comment: @slugonamission
so if i want to change a huge string and i don't care about saving its original value, i should pass it by reference and no local copy shall be made?

Comment: @ofey yes, since the copied variable is discarded when the function exist.

Comment: @ofey Not at all like Java.  In C++, strings have value semantics, and are mutable.  In Java, they have reference semantics, and are immutable.

Answer (score 13):

Why don't you pass by const reference? This way neither will a copy be made, nor will the called function be able to modify the string.

```
int getString(string const &str1)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there will be a difference.

The second variant (without the `&`) will **copy** the string by value into the scope of the `getString` function. This means that any updates you make will affect the local copy, not the caller's copy. This is done by calling the class's copy constructor with the old value (`std::string(std::string& val)`).

On the other hand, the first variant (with the `&`) passes by reference, so changing the local variable will change the caller's variable, unless the reference is marked as const (in which case, you cannot change the value). This *should* be faster since no copy operation needs to happen if you are not changing the string.

Comment: this explanation lacks some information without explaining how the stack works